# How to "Open With" Photoshop CS5.1 in Sublime Text 2 using SideBarEnhancements (WinXP Machine)

Tags: sublimetext2, photoshop, open-with

Does anyone know how to tweak ST2 / SideBarEnhancements (or some other setting) to get .psd files to open in Photoshop CS5.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to enable viewing of `.psd` files in the sidebar, as they're hidden by default. Add the following line to your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings - User`):

```json
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db"],
```

Next, right-click on a `.psd` file in the sidebar and select `Open With -> Edit Applications`.
If you're on OS X, edit `"application"` to point to the **app name**, not the full path. If you're on Windows, put in the full path to the Photoshop `.exe` file, using forward slashes `/` as path delimiters (for example, `C:/Program Files/Adobe/CS5.1/PhotoShop CS5.1/photoshop.exe`, or whatever it is on your system). You can also edit the `"caption"` field to make it more descriptive if you want.

Save the file, and you should now be able to right-click `.psd`, `.png`, `.jpg`, and `.jpeg` files and select `Open With -> Photoshop`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo ... I'll give `C:/Program Files/Adobe/CS5.1/PhotoShop CS5.1/photoshop.exe` a try.

Comment: Awesome, awesome, awesome ... I had been putting off asking about this for a long time. Glad I finally did. And, I actually learned something useful in the process that will help me launch other WinXP apps going forward. `C:/Program Files/Adobe/CS5.1/PhotoShop CS5.1/photoshop.exe` was the solutuon! Thanks @MattDMo

Comment: you seem to be an ST2 specialist @MattDMo. If you get a moment can you peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380253/how-to-integrate-putty-into-sublime-text-2 ? Thanks.