# How to integrate PuTTY into Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, putty

As I learn more about ST2 and use it more, I really like the power and comprehensive capability of running all of my IDE editing activities through the ST2 tool.

I have read and know that it is possible to integrate and emulate a terminal session on a server directly in ST2.

I have PuTTY installed locally on my WinXP machine.

Does anyone have simple step-by-step setup snippet on how to get PuTTY configured in ST2 so you can telnet directly into a server through the ST2 interface?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link for integrating/emulating a terminal session? To my knowledge this isn't really possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text does not support external user interface elements.

The best you can get for the terminal is SublimeREPL:

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

However, this approach is crippled several ways, because Sublime Text is a text editor, not terminal software, and one should not try to force a squere peg in a round hole.

You can still integrate, though. My recommendation is that you try to do a setup where you run both Sublime Text and Putty on your computer, so that the window layout allows easily switch between each other. Also with some scripting you can execute terminal commands from Sublime Text keyboard shortcuts.